# Pass Pasted Clipboard Image From CKeditor to Dropzone

Tags: ckeditor, dropzone.js

We currently have code that handles all our image uploads via Dropzone.js. This includes functionality to paste from the clipboard and upload via dropzone.js, which currently works. This is that event code:

```
document.onpaste = function(event)
{
    alert('pasted');    
    var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
    for (index in items) {
        var item = items[index];
        if (item.kind === 'file') {
          // adds the file to your dropzone instance
          myDropzone.addFile(item.getAsFile());
        }
      }
}
```

Following this, we have added a CKEditor (v4.10) html text editor to that page. The CKEditor has its own clipboard handling built in. If you activate the CKEditor (for example by clicking the text area), the CKEditor effectively takes control of the clipboard from that point. Which is correct, because we want the editor to be able to copy and paste text still.

However, CKEditor does not natively have image uploading built into it. It requires a plugin. But we would prefer not to use this plugin, and rather intercept the paste event, and if the data pasted is an image, pass that along to our dropzone.js handler instead.

While I am able to intercept that event, I am not sure what event data (if any) I can extract from the CKEditor paste event to pass along to the Dropzone handler. Here is the code so far:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.NoteText;   
editor.on( 'paste', function( event )   
{       
   alert('pasted ck');      
   console.dir(event);      
   //myDropzone.addFile(item.getAsFile());  
} );
```

I have tried inspecting the event to see if anything is available for me to use, but don't seem to find anything.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible? Is it possible for me to somehow find and pass along the pasted event data from CKEditor to DropZone? Or am I going to have to implement the CKEditor image upload plugin?

Thanks.